# Override method of UsersController in Clearance

Tags: ruby-on-rails, overriding, clearance

I want to change the

```
  def url_after_create
    '/'
  end
```

of **UsersController** in Clearance.  If I do this:

```
class UsersController < Clearance::UsersController

  protected

  def url_after_create
    '/dashboard'
  end


end
```

When I'm trying to sign up a new user, which works perfectly when not overriding, I get the following: The action 'index' could not be found for UsersController -- The action (post) is to '/users' and it seems that since the index action is not defined it fails.  What should I do?

EDIT: Added code of **Clearance::UsersController**

```
class Clearance::UsersController < ApplicationController
  unloadable

  skip_before_filter :authorize,   :only => [:new, :create]
  before_filter :redirect_to_root, :only => [:new, :create], :if => :signed_in?

  def new
    @user = ::User.new(params[:user])
    render :template => 'users/new'
  end

  def create
    @user = ::User.new(params[:user])
    if @user.save
      sign_in(@user)
      redirect_back_or(url_after_create)
    else
      flash_failure_after_create
      render :template => 'users/new'
    end
  end

  private

  def flash_failure_after_create
    flash.now[:notice] = translate(:bad_email_or_password,
      :scope   => [:clearance, :controllers, :passwords],
      :default => "Must be a valid email address. Password can't be blank.")
      end

  def url_after_create
    '/'
  end
end
```

Comment: can i see the code for `Clearance::UsersController`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This line `match ':controller(/:action(/:id(.:format)))'` located in **routes** was causing the trouble.  Commenting that solved it.